# Hide/remove the stat_smooth line above ymax value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to to hide/remove the stat_smooth line above ymax value in a spaghetti plot

E.g.,

In this example model

```
fit <- brm(count ~ zAge + zBase * Trt + (1 | patient),
           data = epilepsy, family = poisson(), chains = 3, cores = 3)

conditional_effects(fit, spaghetti = T , ndraws = 100, effects = 'zBase')
```

Results this one
[image]

Now, I would like to remove the average fit line (in white here) when it passes the 100 in yaxis

What I've done is to get the spagetti plot and its data

```
spagetti_plot <- conditional_effects(fit, spaghetti = T , ndraws = 100)    
spagetti_plot_data <- attr(spagetti_plot[[1]], "spaghetti")
```

Replicate the above plot and try to adjust the `stat_smooth` using the `xseq`. However I would like to use something like `yseq` (which doesn't exist here apparently)

```
ggplot(data = spagetti_plot_data, aes(x = effect1__, y = estimate__, group = sample__)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = effect1__, y = estimate__, group = sample__)) +
  stat_smooth( aes(x = effect1__, y = estimate__, group = 1) , 
              fullrange = F, xseq = seq(0,3, length=80))
```

[image]

Is there a way to hide the average trend line above an y-axis limit (say 30)?